# How to get Magento customer data BEFORE Mage::run?

Tags: magento

before loading the store, I want to get some customer data and than decide which storeview to load. But it does not work just like that:

```
// Option 1
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); // does not work before Framework is loaded


// Option 2
Mage::app();
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); // does work but...
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); // produces here the following error: "Mage registry key "controller" already exists"
```

So, how to load customer data and then load the shop?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to accomplish this, since the store has to initialise itself to provide you with the models you want to work with.

The only way i can think of is pulling them out of the database directly without any Magento classes, since I think the Autoloader itself is not initialised yet.

Edit:

Try Mage::app('your_store_view_name)

Comment: Right, but how do you manually start the front end after initializing the framework with Mage::app(); ?